# Creating Excel ranges that are dependent on another range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel **First range** which consists of four columns (A-D) and five rows (1-5).

The cells in this range consist of numbers.

I want to set up two other ranges - an Excel **Second range** and an Excel **Third range** on another worksheet.

I want both ranges to be identical to the Excel First range, except that the numbers in the Second range are double the values of those in the First range, and those in the Third range are triple the values of those in the First range.

I also want the Third range to be positioned just below the Second range.

I also want that if I add new rows or columns to the First range, and those cells have numbers, then the Second and Third ranges automatically adds the new rows and columns as well, except that the number values in the Second and Third ranges are double and triple those of those in the First ranges, respectively.

Is this possible? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: This would be very simple to do with formulas if the ranges were in separate columns.  Your requirement that the third range be located below the second one means you'll need to use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

**Since your question has many twists therefore I'm dividing the Query in Three Parts.**

**Part 1:**

*Copy First Range into other Sheet as Second & Third Range.*

Create Command button on Sheet1 and use this VBA Code,

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A1:D5").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lastrow)

End Sub
```

**Part 2:**
Create Command button on Sheet 2.

**Set it's CAPTION as Double**.

Use this VBA Code,

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

If CommandButton2.Caption = "Double" Then

Dim rngData As Range

    Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:D5")
    rngData = Evaluate(rngData.Address & "*2")
    CommandButton2.Caption = "Triple"


ElseIf CommandButton2.Caption = "Triple" Then

Dim rngData1 As Range

    Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A6:D10")
    rngData = Evaluate(rngData.Address & "*3")
    CommandButton2.Caption = "Double"
   End If

End Sub
```

**Part 3:**

*Now, how to update Range 2 and 3 with modifications in Range 1.*

For this the most easiest I can suggest you.

Copy Range One with some EXTRA Rows and Columns and use PASTE LINK.

**Note,** In this Case DON'T USE PART ONE of my Solution.

*Hope this help you.*